# Summarize paired values by category mysql or dax

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, powerbi

Although I fought my battles alone up to now, i would really appreciate some help on this.
I am reading forums and infos the last couple of day, but with no success, so I am bothering you now.

Here is the task:

There are two columns, receipts and articles:

[image]

I need to count how many couples of articles are there in a single receipt. That is, to determine which articles are sold the most often with other ones.

The end result should be something like this - table with first, second article and number of times they are matched.

[image]

Any help with SQL or DAX/Power Bi/ would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is A-B-2? I do not see...

Comment: The combination A + B occurs 2 times in the dataset /in two different receipts/. Thanks

Comment: *combination A + B occurs 2 times* WHERE??? I see only one - for Receipt=1.

Comment: Sorry, you are totally right - my mistake from trying to simplify the table. This combination occurs only once.

Comment: Does `(receiptno, article)` is defined as UNIQUE by the index in source table?

Comment: No, there is only one Primary Key in the table, which is Auto Increment value.

Comment: *No, there is only one Primary Key in the table* UNIQUE index is enough - it may be not primary key. I'd recommend you to create it. And - imagine that some record(s) are doubled by some reason/error... you must get DISTINCT before pairing and other calculations.

Comment: Already done, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to self-join the table, then aggregate:

```
select
    t1.article article1,
    t2.article article2,
    count(*)
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.receiptno = t2.receiptno and t1.article < t2.article
group by t1.article, t2.article
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the code, adjusted according to the actual table, but it starts and times out eventually.